# Django Model: ForeignKey and Relations

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
   pass

class Vote(models.Model):
      post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
      user = models.ForeignKey(django.contrib.auth.models.User)
```

I want to allow logged User to make a vote on Post's Admin site. I think about 2 solution as below:

1. Add 'voted' field to Post model.
2. Customize Post's Admin forms by add a Button control and implement do_vote() function in Post model to call when the Button is clicked.

Do you have any other solutions?
Additionally, I don't know how to implement 2 above solutions.
Could you give me some lines of code?

Answer (score 1):

On your `PostAdmin` class you can add an action:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    actions = [vote_on_post,]
```

and then you can implement the `vote_on_post` method based on [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#adding-actions-to-the-modeladmin), should be something like this:

```
@admin.action(description='Vote on action')
def vote_on_post(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    user = request.user
    for post in queryset:
        Vote.objects.create(user=user,post=post)
```

You probably want to add logic to prevent multiple votes from the same user on the same post, etc.

Comment: Not only logic but also a unique constraint on those two fields using `unique_together`.